# header vs content redirect

Tags: php, html, http-headers

As we know it, the `header()` function in PHP causes error ouputs unless sent before an HTML content, so instead of using output buffering or worse yet, suppressing the famous "headers already sent " error, I was thinking of using the HTML content redirect as an alternative. ex:

```
if($userRegister){ ?>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=success.php" /> 
<?php }
```

As I have not seen this approach, I would like to know there is something I am missing. Because it seems quite a good approach for page redirection

Comment: In my opinion, the best thing to do is to work your application from the start to handle this properly. Don't make it hard to do redirects when you need to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it good practise to use meta refresh tags for redirects instead of header() function in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529379/is-it-good-practise-to-use-meta-refresh-tags-for-redirects-instead-of-header-f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see: [Is it good practise to use meta refresh tags for redirects instead of header() function in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529379/is-it-good-practise-to-use-meta-refresh-tags-for-redirects-instead-of-header-f)

both methods have their ups and downs.

in my opinion it is better to use `header()` as it sends a smaller payload to the client and it won't cause side effects from the browser loading the DOM of another page.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't required, but I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
if($userRegister){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">location.href="success.php";</script>
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=success.php" /></noscript> 
<?php }
```

Answer (score 1):

i would personally use [`headers_sent`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) instead of checking a specific variable since that's why the function was created in the first place

```
if (headers_sent()) {
  echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=success.php" />'
}
```

i also suggest creating redirect method so you don't have to test the headers each time in different parts of your code

```
function redirect($target) {
  if (headers_sent()) {
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; URL={$target}\" />";
  } else {
    header("Location: {$target}");
  }
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used meta refresh as an alternative of header location. It's right but in my opinion you should use header redirect and if you want to remove `header already sent` error than you should use `ob_start()` and `ob_flush()` and turn on the output buffering your php.ini if it's off.