# It is possible to create any application using header() without output buffering

Tags: php

Everytime I create a website or application in PHP I must use the header() function to redirect people from page to page, but since the typical header is almost always sent before  I find myself having to use output buffering functions that slow down the page. It's either that or suppress the "header already sent" errors. I just can't really find any example where an application can be built in PHP without having to violate either the two.

I am trying to know more, about how some redirect to pages without using output buffering.

### edit

This is what some people assume *is* the possible.

```
<?php
$stack_errors = NULL;
if($_POST && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

 $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users where username = ? AND password = ?');
 $stmt->execute(array($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
 if($stmt->rowCount() == 0){
   $stack_errors = 'error, username or password is incorrect';
 }else{
   $stack_errors = false; 
 }
}else{
  $stack_errors = 'please enter username and password to log in';
}
if(false === $stack_errors){
  header('Location: /success.php');
  exit;
}
?>
<html> 
<head></head>
<body>
<form>
 <input ...>
 <input ...>
 <?php if($stack_errors){
   echo $stack_errors; 
 }
<form>
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, just send the header before anything

Comment: It looks to me you're just doing it all wrong if you're setting headers twice and getting that warn.

Comment: Separate business logic from presentation logic and perform `header()` redirects before outputting anything to the screen.

Comment: From the looks of [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24482385/) why are you asking this now?

Comment: @showdev Trust me it is not possible. In every case I have tried, there must be some content sent before the header() for the application not to break.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Because [the I found out meta refresh was a bad idea too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529379/is-it-good-practise-to-use-meta-refresh-tags-for-redirects-instead-of-header-f)

Comment: trust us, it IS possible. Unless you have no control over the code and you've been hired to only touch a small portion of the code. why don't you provide sample code?

Comment: If you had a sample piece of code, we may be able to help you. Usually, you'd want to use header within a conditional statement which usually works best. If that doesn't work, then you may have a byte order mark problem somewhere; way too broad a subject at this point in time.

Comment: Note that suppressing the "header already sent" error doesn't solve the problem.  Even if you suppress the message, your custom header will still be ignored because it's too late to send it.

Comment: @KaiQing **OK, I have update the question by creating** a small script as to what *I Know* you are referring to as POSSIBLE. Now you know, what I am not asking for.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Check the update. Using the simple script I just wrote, `header()` can be used without a problem. But that is a simple case scenario. You can not do the same thing for a very huge application. Only people who have worked on huge project can know what I mean

Comment: @EmilioGort Now you know that is not what I am asking

Comment: It doesn't matter how big the project is if your `header()` call is in a `<?php` block at the very beginning of the file.  It sounds like you're saying that your example code *doesn't* exhibit the problem, so it's still unclear what exactly you're having trouble with.

Comment: @spartak If you're so convinced that it's impossible that you assume anyone saying otherwise had less experience than you, why even ask?

Comment: @spartak you must be working on some badly written programs then.

Comment: @Wyzard Ok, just try to understand it this way. Say I have a small costume built framework. Now, the `public/index.php` file called the `app/boostrap.php` file, the bootstrap loads many files including config and other files before it loads controllers/view [where the header() function is found] so, architecturally it is impossible to initiate a header() before any html/php output

Comment: Try and do away with `else{
  $stack_errors = 'please enter username and password to log in';
}` see if that'll make it disappear. Then instead of `else{
   $stack_errors = false; ` put your header there.

Comment: See the paragraph I added to my answer.  Just make sure you don't have any extraneous BOM/whitespace output in any of your included files and you should be OK.  None of what you're including sounds like it's *meant* to produce output.

Comment: @IMSoP I am convinced it is impossible for me, so I would like to know how people do it. So far, I haven't gotten any answer

Comment: You've asked how to do it, and people have told you how to do it, and you've said "no, it's impossible".  If you're convinced that it's impossible to avoid doing output before a `header()` call, then delete your question (since it has no possible answer) and stop wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @spartak You should read this [How to fix “Headers already sent” error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php/8028987#8028987)

Comment: @Wyzard I know how to do it. That is why I provided the code *showing* how to do it. I still don't think most people got the real question. If you feel you are personally wasting your time, you are free to leave this question

Comment: "before any html/php output" - this phrase may be the key to your misunderstanding: running PHP code does not, of itself, create any output, unless it involves functions explicitly designed to do so such as `echo`. It's perfectly possible to write an application that runs thousands of lines worth of PHP code, across dozens of different files, without a single byte of output being produced.

Comment: "I still don't think most people got the real question." If that's the case, you might want to re-state the real question to help clarify.

Comment: @IMSoP `It's perfectly possible to write an application ... without a single byte of output being produced` So you are saying that most (reputable) frameworks out there which have thousands of lines and files are letting page redirects anywhere inside the controller without outputting a single byte of code and without using output buffering?

Comment: Well I guess I don't get it neither or am not grasping the question. I'm going to get me some popcorn. ;-)

Comment: ob_start(output buffering) in this case is just a work around to hide the problem, isn't the real solution.

Comment: @spartak In a word, yes.

Comment: @EmilioGort That is what I am saying. ob_start() would slow down my application, and is considered a hack to some level. So, that is out of the question for me.

Comment: @IMSoP I would love to read a simple answer on how that is done. Because that is what I am searching for

Comment: your problem is right here, in your own quote: " loads controllers/view [where the header() function is found]" why on earth are you doing script processing in a view? Why is this not in the controller? If you are asking how to use header() AFTER output, then you're right, it is impossible without using output buffer or you will get a warning. Otherwise, maybe you can explain why you don't have access to run this process in the proper place instead of within a view

Comment: This example might be helpful, generally regarding redirects in a MVC structure: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?464164-Redirects-in-MVC

Comment: @spartak I have already written an answer. It's in the section of this page labelled "answers". If there is something you don't understand about it, feel free to add a comment underneath it.

Comment: I think it is better that I ask another question asking, how some good full-stack frameworks manage to let users redirect inside the controller without using ob_start() or suppressing the error. After clearly having send many non-header outputs before it

Comment: @spartak "After clearly having send many non-header outputs before it" - what makes you think a well-engineered framework would have sent output before a redirect? What would the purpose of such output be?

Comment: It all boils down to properly structuring your framework so that there's nothing being echo'ed until it's time to do so, or giving them access to an area. Since this is a login-related APP, you're better off (and if you're not already using this) using sessions inside all pages. Proper conditional statements while not echoing messages as you're presently doing. If a criteria isn't met, redirect. Don't play around inside the gray area. *That's my take on all this.*

Comment: Well, I rather just get laravel and see how the redirect is done, even after the comments in the controller which should be enough to cause some problems are handled. 
Thanks for all the comments and answers

Comment: If I may add another suggestion. If you plan on rebuilding or using another framework, test it slowly at a smaller scale. Once you know that nothing will cause havoc, then keep going following that same convention. I fell into that trap "once", built a whole bunch of pages, only to be forced to totally rethink/rebuild the whole concept; I was not a happy camper. *Live & Learn* as they say ;-) Thinking for an hour or a day may save you a lot of time and aggravation; it has for me and that's how I work now. *Cheers*

Answer (score 5):

A well-written application should not have a problem with output being sent "too early", and causing PHP to issue HTTP headers:

Firstly, decisions which might lead to a redirect should happen during processing of input and making business decisions; this code should be entirely complete before any content is output to the page. This ensures that your classes and functions have a single responsibility, and allows you - at least in theory - to replace the output without rewriting the whole application, e.g. to create a machine-readable API version. Contrary to your comments, the importance of this principle *increases* when you are working on larger projects.

Secondly, PHP itself might output errors and warnings, but these should be turned off on production systems using the `display_errors` ini setting. You don't want users seeing the gory details of every mistake in your code - at best, they'll judge it; at worst, they'll probe it for security holes.

Thirdly, others have pointed out issues with stray whitespace outside PHP tags, and Unicode BOMs added by editors. These can be tricky to track down, but by no means impossible - a decent editor will have functions to show whitespace, and to save without a BOM. Trailing whitespace can be avoided by not using a closing `?>`, since it is implied at the end of a file. A small amount of output will also be swallowed if you use the gzip "output filter"; this doesn't buffer the whole output, but will buffer a few bytes at a time so it has something to compress, so gives you a bit of a get-out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there is not a line here that supports [your claim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520823/it-is-possible-to-create-any-application-using-header-without-output-buffering#comment37966736_24520823)

Comment: @spartak I have absolutely no idea what proof you are expecting to see. I can only repeat this sentence from my answer, which is a key part of designing a good web application framework: "decisions which might lead to a redirect should happen ... before any content is output to the page". It is up to you when to output content, so it is up to you to design your application to separate logic from display.

Comment: I think what he wants is that some one gives him the code ready to go so he can easily use it as he is not capable of understanding it from the many open sources frameworks out there that already does that.

Comment: @Prix The problem is that that's impossible to provide, because it's an *absence* of code, not a magic function: I could write whatever code I liked, and as long as it didn't use `echo` or similar, it would be an example of code that didn't output anything. At the end of it, I could add a `header()` call, and be guaranteed not to get an error from it.

Comment: @IMSoP what I was not saying for you to write a code, merely that he would not rest until some one put up some code to show how its done.

Comment: @Prix Yeah, I meant "unfortunately for the OP, nobody can provide that".

Comment: @IMSoP Yeah, my problem is that you dismissed any doubts and held the notion that all frameworks don't use output buffering for the redirect mechanism. While, you can see [the laravel index](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/index.php) file itself has comments all over even before running the whole application. Which supports my claim and suggest that a header [of comments] *IS* already sent. So, they are using buffering or similar hacks. [somewhere inside the reponse-related classes]

Comment: @Prix Well, I hope that brought you some happiness. But I am not looking for a code.

Comment: @spartak neither for answers since you didn't seem pleased with any of it even thought many of it were the right answer.

Comment: @spartak Those are PHP comments; they don't produce any output or headers. As [I suspected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520823/it-is-possible-to-create-any-application-using-header-without-output-buffering/24520902?noredirect=1#comment37966639_24520823) you seem to be under the impression that just running code - or, in this case, skipping over comments - will cause PHP to produce output. That is quite simply not the case, unless that code explicitly uses `echo`, `?>`, or some other function whose explicit role is to output something to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Headers are only sent when your PHP page produces output.  If your file begins *immediately* with a `<?php` block (no whitespace, Unicode BOM, etc. before it), it won't produce any output before you get a chance to set your custom headers.

If your code is including/requiring any other PHP files before setting headers, make sure those files don't do any unwanted output either.  Even if your include file is nothing but a big `<?php` block, check for whitespace/BOM at the beginning as well as whitespace at the end (such as a newline after the `?>`).

Comment: Not to mention an (invisible to the naked eye) byte order mark which also counts as output, a cookie etc. Far too broad a subject and many make those common mistakes.

Comment: Good point, watch out for your editor putting a BOM at the beginning of the file.  (Since PHP isn't Unicode-aware, PHP pages shouldn't have a Unicode BOM anyway.)

Comment: Exactly and I "once" was a victim of it (lol) The operative word being "once" ;-)

Comment: How can I check the BOM, some times when I make a copy & paste from netbean to sublime I got errors (I think BOM) and I have type the full code again, how can I avoid that?

Comment: ^--< A question within a question?

Comment: Make sure you're saving the file as something like ASCII, not UTF-8 or UTF-16 (which may be labeled as "Unicode").

Comment: A BOM or small amount of stray whitespace can be worked around by enabling gzip compression, which buffers output until it has enough to start the compressed stream.

Comment: But the BOM shouldn't be there anyway.  If it's output, it means it's being sent to the browser, which may be fooled into thinking that the response is Unicode when it's really something else.

Comment: @Wyzard Well, there's plenty of reasons why the output *would* be Unicode, although if it's UTF-8, which is pretty much standard for the web, the BOM is pretty meaningless. I definitely disagree with the advice to save as ASCII; maybe ISO8859-15 at a pinch (so you have £ and € in standard locations, and a reasonable selection of European diacritics).

Comment: I have for default ISO-8859-9

Answer (score 0):

Of course the header in the HTTP protocol is sent as first in the response. That's the reason it is called "header". You have to ensure in your code logic, that headers are sent before any other output. If you want to process and output any data before you make the decision which headers are to be sent, there is no other way than output buffering. PHP then does the job for you. You can flush and end output buffering as soon as you are sure that no further headers are to be sent.