# Make PHP form do nothing if field is empty

Tags: php, forms

At this moment I have a small contact-box on my page that ask for telephone number.

If no number is entered the form should do nothing. Instead of sending a empty email to my client. 
It is not necessary that the form creates a message or something else if the field is empty.
I just want to have extra php code, that makes sure nothings happening if somebody clicks the send button while the field is left empty.

This is my code:

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$EmailTo = "INFO@EPIMMO.BE";
$Subject = "Vraagt om hem te bellen - Website Epimmo";
$free = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['free']));

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";

$Body .= "Volgend telefoonnummer werd ingevoerd via uw website:";
$Body .= $free;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://www.epimmo.be/hire-us-phone.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

Thanks for reading and a hopefully a solution ;-)

Kristof

Comment: Can you share your html as well ?

Comment: @Stan Kosmoseistis Why you need PHP code to prevent form submission use HTML 5 validation or any jQuery validation on client to prevent form submission, if you want to do on server then check with `isset($variable)` is your variable  is set then allow submission else redirect.

Comment: @Stan Kosmoseistis use ajax to check validation on server side so there will be not effect on the page except notification telling empty input

Answer (score 2):

First you can add if condition that will check email or phone number is not blank 
and in its not blank then execute next code of sending an email.

```
if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email']!="") 
{
 //write here your code to send an email
}
```

Comment: Given the code sample provided, that the form has already "done something", that is, it has been submitted already to this action page, the above answer is the normal and correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with HTML like this:

```
<input type="number" required></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just after `<?php` you could add the following code:

```
if(!isset($_POST['free']) || empty($_POST['free']) {
    header('location: /hire-us-phone.php');
    exit;
}
```

`header('location: /hire-us-phone.php');` will do a header redirect to `/hire-us-phone.php` (which is much better than using a meta refresh) and `exit;` will ensure no code after the header redirect will be run.

Comment: Everybody's down on the OP for using META REFRESH. Everybody says "header location is better", but no one can say why header location is better. Yes, it's pure php. So what? How does that translate to better?

Comment: The headers are read before the body of HTTP responses. It's easier for the developer and more efficient for the client (even if by a small fraction).

Answer (score 0):

To redirect, you should be using:

```
header("Location: your-url.php");
exit;
```

This code would need to go before anything is echoed, including whitespace.

Also, what is this code?

```
// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
```

Clearly, the if statement will never be false.

You could validate the easy way, such as one big if statement. But a better way is to do something like this:

```
if($_POST['email'] == ''){
  $_SESSION['my_form']['errors']['email'] = 'The email was left blank';
}
if(!empty($_SESSION['my_form']['errors'])){
  // redirect & exit here
}
```

And then on your form page, you can use this session data to display a relevant error to the user:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['my_form']['errors']['email'])){
  // output $_SESSION['my_form']['errors']['email'] here to the user
}
```

Comment: Explain why header location is better than meta refresh.

Comment: @InfiniteLoop Your question already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4529383/1094772

Comment: @rybo111 why redirect as OP is asking form should do nothing?

Comment: @JiteshNK Form handling logic should always redirect somewhere, otherwise you get the dreaded "Are you sure you want to resubmit this form?" message if you navigate back to the page.

Comment: @rybo111 I am not telling to resubmit the form OP can use the ajax to check on server whether the input field is set or not, if not set error message should be passed, like this form will do nothing means all process will be done behind the scene.

Comment: @rybo111 I am not telling you are wrong here, I am just focusing on sentence that OP has written `form should do nothing`. Let me know if I am wrong or I am in wrong direction.

Comment: @JiteshNK Having logic using only AJAX fails if the user has JavaScript disabled. You can still use AJAX with the session method. The OP said, "Form should do nothing. Instead of sending a empty email to my client" which I understand to mean he wants to validate and **not** send an empty email. Since adding the `required` property only works with certain browsers (and can be removed by the user maliciously), you still need some PHP logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we're presented with the action page, which means something has already happened: The form was submitted, and redirected to the action page.

As @Mohini pointed out, you can test the condition of an empty field on the action page.

But after the submit button is pressed, you can easily use javascript on the form page to test if the required fields are populated.

(plain vanilla javascript)

```
if(! document.forms['formname']['email'].value == "" ){
    document.forms['formname'].sumit();
} else {
    // do nohing. Or do something. I don't really care!
}
```